# Would like some specifications on Lorentz Force effects

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I understand the general "how" Lorentz Force affects a given particle based on contributing factors of electric charge(s) and magnetic field directions, but not as much as I'd like.

For instance--if a concentrated electrical charge hits a supermagnet connected to a metal chassis, what would occur? Vice versa, if I used a variant magnetic force on something with an electrical charge, would similar effects occur, or would they differ?

If anyone can break down what Lorentz Force can do when one of the two factors is added to the other undesirably into a more manageable scope, I would be greatly appreciative.

-Lamda

Comment: I would probably approximate the magnetic field by the wings as 1 or 2 "perfect magnetic dipoles" and calculate the field by the electric charged ball using the "biot savart law for point charge". I'm not sure about the converse case because.. there is no such thing as a magnetic charge ;)

Comment: This question is about [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), not physics which would be useful to other users.

Comment: Actually, I asked how the two related parts of the force related to one another and what the effects of hypothetical scenarios would be.

I didn't ask anything involving programming, scenario design, balancing, or any of the other facets of game development. I asked for specifics on how the Lorentz Force works, and provided the relevant context for which I would be using that information so that people had an understanding.

If asking about how physics works is okay, but asking about how physics works in a non-real-world scenario isn't, maybe you need to reconsider what "useful" means.

Comment: OP edited, context removed altogether, questions reworded to eliminate the "useless" context (while still asking the same thing).

If the explanation for why this was moved is meaning what I think it does, I should note that I'm not asking for mathematical formulas and equations--I'm asking what the _physical_ effects would be in scenarios occurring under certain conditions. The "effort" I'm accused of not putting in has _been_ made, as the unedited original states--all I came up with and found were equations, or little to no information from which I could infer probable effects or outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the behavior of the electromagnetic field beyond only Lorentz, there are some interesting effects that you can use for inspiration. The Maxwell equations describe the field's full behavior, but I have to admit they are hard to grasp for me as well. My answer is therefore not very technical.

**Attacking with electricity**

In your example of throwing a massively charged object into a strong magnetic field, this is similar to what the solar wind does to Earth. Basically, its magnet could work to divert the lightning, but the charges would be led into the poles of the magnet, the wings. Which wing depends on the charge of the ball (it could be electrons or it could be ions). Basically the path of the ball would bend and home in on the poles. This is the auroras on Earth. If the velocity is not right, however, it might be deflected?

If the particles come in fast, that could work as radiation. It could generate heat. Or if they attach to the metal, it will become electrically charged. If opposite charges are put on the wings, those charges will want to combine together. If the wing is a U-magnet, they will simply travel down along it easily. If there is flesh between the wings, there might be a point when the charges zap the boss to get across. If the boss' flesh is not that electrically conductive, then the two wings will gradually move closer together, deforming the boss if necessary. If the ball lightning is overwhelmingly strong, you might break its back right away.

**Attacking with magnetism**

In your example, the projectile does not have to be a magnet, which means the magnetism would not hit the boss itself. And oppositely charged particles will repel, so this could potentially work to push the boss if the projectile is heavy enough. It will stop in its path to the boss, at which time the boss might be able to grab it and launch it back at you. However, there could be a more direct approach too.

For an electrically charged boss, a massive magnetic field could dictate their motion. In reality this would not be easy, but hey, this is a game. Using a varying magnetic field, you could either force the boss to flip and hit its head on the ground (only possible if its charge is distributed away from the centre of mass), or move it sideways to slam into an object. While you try to control the magnetic field, the boss could brace in a certain way to prevent moving. Stay one step ahead and the boss gets slammed. Of course, this boss would be wise to wear opposite-charge armour to become electrically neutral, unless it wishes to unleash the electric power. It'll be vulnerable to magnetic manipulation once the armour is broken, or right before it attacks.

As for a more flashy reaction, if the boss is wearing armor made of individual pieces, these will align in the magnetic field like iron dust around a magnet. You can also imagine manipulating a field of such particles in the air (they will not stand still but try to move along the field lines, which for a magnetic field are always loops terminating at the source). Iron as a conductor will also gain its own electric field near the boss, because its electrons will be moved by the field. This will help the boss, and it can start a clash of opposing forces. Now, if you had a magical ability to reverse the charge in those iron pieces, that would turn push to pull. You'd have the upper hand, and the boss' field would aid in stabbing itself with these metal projectiles. That also goes for the boss: if it physically flips a projectile during the clash of forces, it will come sailing back to you.

I might have made some errors of intuition here. Electromagnetism is not my strongest field, so I'd try to verify the physical logic of this, especially the last paragraph.